# Building PlayFramework with sbt fails withUnmappableCharacterException

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.0

I am trying to build play framework locally and I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last Play-JDBC-Evolutions/compile:createHeaders for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last Play/compile:createHeaders for the full output.
[error] (Play-JDBC-Evolutions/compile:createHeaders) java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
[error] (Play/compile:createHeaders) java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
[error] Total time: 35 s, completed 22-Dec-2017 13:31:24
```

I have tried to:

1. set logLevel := Level.Debug
2. run last Play/compile:createHeaders

But I am new to sbt and these actions didn't provide me with more debug information.

The error might be linked to [the incorrect source encoding](https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/issues/134).

I am using source files from: [official github repo](https://github.com/playframework/playframework)
My sbt version: 1.0.4
Error log: [gist](https://gist.github.com/batousik/c45e79c8483684f2618c2d543d16860c)

Comment: You should include sbt version and `build.sbt` and `project/*.sbt` in the question. The error looks indeed related to the incorrect encoding, so have you checked your sources encoding?

Answer (score 0):

OUTDATED (see below):
I just tried to build playframework 2.6.15 and there are funky characters in the comments of the code like “ ” that crash compile on Windows 10.  If you remove all the comments from each file that "last Play/compile:createHeaders" complains about, you should be able to compile.  I had to remove all the comments from RequestHeader.scala, Render.scala, Jasonp.scala, package.scala and then I was able to compile.  I also had to delete the test directory in order to publishLocal as there were special characters in some tests.  I suspect the problem is that someone needs to put something like scalacOptions ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8") in the right place but I don't know where that is.

UPDATE: Solution is to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 to SBT_OPTS environment variable. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8449